# How to manage User Roles in a Database?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm creating a website in which I will be managing users and their permissions. I am looking to implement user roles, and can't seem to wrap my head around how things should work. I want to be able to assign a user a certain role, and have each role contain one to several permissions that can be read easily by my script. Just want to know how I should go about setting up my database to do this easily and efficiently.

In my head I picture 3 tables (users, roles, and permissions). I could give each user a role id that joins the roles table, I just don't know how I can link roles to several permissions.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> I just don't know how I can link roles
>   to several permissions.

You use a join table: role_id and permission_id to identify what permissions are associated with which roles

EDIT:

Example tables

**ROLE Table**

```
Role_ID Role_Name
1       Standard User
2       Super User
3       Guest
```

**PERMISSION Table**

```
Permission_ID Permission_Name
1             View User List
2             Update Own User Account
3             Update Any User Account
```

**ROLE_PERMISSION Table**

```
Role_ID Permission_ID
1       1    // Role 1 (Standard User) grants View User List
1       2    //        and Update Own User Account
2       1    // Role 2 (Super User) grants View User List,
2       2    //        Update Own User Account,
2       3    //        and Update Any User Account
3       1    // Role 3 (Guest) grants View User List
```

Listing the permissions for a specified Role_ID

```
select R.role_id,
       P.permission_id,
       P.permission_name
  from role R,
       permission P,
       role_permission RP
 where RP.permission_id = P.permission_id
   and RP.role_id = R.role_id
   and R.role_id = 1
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark, excellent help. Now, say I have a role Graphic Designer and he does not have permission to view anyones profile but his own. I have assigned him a user to take care of and he needs access to the user's profile. How can I store in the Database that he has the right to view any profile that he has been assigned to?

Comment: @In God I Trust - That gets quite a bit more complex; I'd set up a 4th permission of "Update Managed User Accounts" and create another table of manager->user relationships; tying that into the security code for the 4th permission; probably creating a role of "Manager" with that as a permission for the new role

Answer (score 6):

I Think bitwise operator are the best way to implement user permission.
Here I am showing how we can implement it with Mysql.

Below is a sample tables with some sample data:

**Table 1** : Permission table to store permission name along with it bit like 1,2,4,8..etc (multiple of 2)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `permission` (
  `bit` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bit`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Insert some sample data into the table.

```
INSERT INTO `permission` (`bit`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'User-Add'),
(2, 'User-Edit'),
(4, 'User-Delete'),
(8, 'User-View'),
(16, 'Blog-Add'),
(32, 'Blog-Edit'),
(64, 'Blog-Delete'),
(128, 'Blog-View');
```

**Table 2**: User table to store user id,name and role. Role will be calculated as sum of permissions.
Example :
If user 'Ketan' having permission of 'User-Add' (bit=1) and 'Blog-Delete' (bit-64) so role will be 65 (1+64).
If user 'Mehata' having permission of 'Blog-View' (bit=128) and 'User-Delete' (bit-4) so role will be 132 (128+4).

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `role` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Sample data-

```
INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `name`, `role`, `created_date`)
   VALUES (NULL, 'Ketan', '65', '2013-01-09 00:00:00'),
   (NULL, 'Mehata', '132', '2013-01-09 00:00:00');
```

Loding permission of user
After login if we want to load user permission than we can query below to get the permissions:

```
SELECT permission.bit,permission.name  
   FROM user LEFT JOIN permission ON user.role & permission.bit
 WHERE user.id = 1
```

Here user.role "&" permission.bit is a Bitwise operator which will give output as -

```
User-Add - 1
Blog-Delete - 64
```

If we want to check weather a particular user have user-edit permission or not-

```
  SELECT * FROM `user` 
     WHERE role & (select bit from permission where name='user-edit')
```

Output = No rows.

You can see also : http://goo.gl/ATnj6j

Answer (score 4):

This is how I usually what I do:

You define a set of permissions whose meaning varies from target object to target object, but whose general meaning is the same. For instance:

- read
- write
- append
- delete
- delete contents
- read permissions
- change permissions

Then you assign a bit to each of those:

```
class Perms {
    const read           = 1;
    const write          = 2;
    const append         = 4;
    const delete         = 8;
    const deleteContents = 16;
    const readPerm       = 32;
    const changePerm     = 64;
    /* shortcuts */
    const fullControl    = 127; 
    const noControl      = 0;
}
```

Then for each type of object you have a table where you insert pairs `(user, perms)`, `(group, perms)`, `(role, perms)` or whatever you want to associate with the permissions.

You can query the permissions of the user (which may have several roles) like this:

```
//this will depend on the database
//you could also use whatever bitwise OR aggregate your database has
//to avoid the foreach loop below
$query = new Query(
    "select perm from objects_permissions as P ".
    "where P.id_object = \$1 and " .
    "   (P.role = any(\$2));",
    $obj->getId(), $user->getRoles()
);

$perms = 0;
foreach ($query as $row) {
    $perms |= $row['perm']; 
}
```

You can also add deny permissions with little difficulty.

Comment: I'll confess to using a similar mechanism for defining user access to objects within an application; but a user/role/permission mechanism similar to that requested by the OP for access to general UI functionality (e.g UPLOAD_FILE permission)

Comment: @Mark My approach is to generalize. If I need to control access to upload files, I define a "uploaded files container" and grant users `append` permissions in such object. You can then easily add other related permissions, for instance `deleteContents` on that container could allow deleting uploaded files, `read` would allow downloading files or list them, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go the route of the 3 tables, you could create your tables like so:

```
Table       | Rows
User        | id ; name ; dob ; permission_id ; etc...  
Roles       | id ; add_post ; edit_post ; delete_post ; add_user ; etc...
Permissions | id ; user_id ; role_id
```

Answer (score 0):

We have managed with two table using json datatype so we does not need any repeating entry like

```
Role_ID Permission_ID
1       1    
1       2
```

```
Role Table

id, role_name
'1', 'read'
'2', 'write'
'3', 'update'
'4', 'all'
```

```
User Table

id,   name,   role_assign, role_type
'1', 'arjun', '[1, 2]',    'admin'
'2', 'dhruv', '[3, 4]',    'user'
```

```
Query

SELECT u.id,r.role_name,u.name FROM test.users u inner join
test.role r on JSON_CONTAINS(u.role_assign, cast(r.id as json));
```

```
Output

id,  role_name, name
'1', 'read',   'arjun'
'1', 'write',  'arjun'
'2', 'update', 'dhruv'
'2', 'all',    'dhruv'
```