# PHP (phpMyAdmin) & MySQL with Dreamweaver

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, dreamweaver

Im doing an online reservation system for my project and im stuck. I'm working on this login which all my log in information is retrieved from my database on  my phpMyAdmin and its working . what i want is that i have 2 tables on my database one for student and one for administrators, what i want is that i want to differentiate this 2 when logging in. eg something like for student : S200400687 and admin can be something else like his name eg. adam.kingston. and each log in will be directed to there own page according to their privileges.

please can anyone tell me what to do or a tutorial i can refer to and Thank you sooo much for your Help :)

Comment: Please post what you have done till now. You don't require 2 table to achieve what you are doing. Just redirect them according to a flag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to manage User Roles in a Database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213610/how-to-manage-user-roles-in-a-database)

Comment: i dont know how i can post what ive done because in dreamweaver i used the shortcut method or whatever u call it where i just click Insert>Data Objects> User Authentication and inserted the values the codes just automatically generated. same for creating the connection.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but it has some "okay" topics - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B1_yi7HM0Cg

Comment: I know security was not part of the question, but security for login systems are a NIGHTMARE. If security is a concern for you, don't do what I did .... tried to create my own security. Find a proven security that has already been created by someone who is a lot smarter than you and I.

Comment: thanks alot for the heads up... i will try what you said. thanks